# Replace float in div class with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

To begin with, I have some experience with JavaScript but mostly with client side scripting of programs and not JavaScript in a Web envoirement.

What I'm trying to do is to fetch and replace the vlaue in this class:

```
<div class="detailPrice" style="float:left;width:180px"> € 20,90* </div>
```

The value changes on every page. So I can't search for this specific value.
When I got the value I want to assign it to a variable like

```
price = 20.9
```

do some math to it and then replace my new value with the old one.

Thanks for any sort of help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll()` to get the div(s) and use regex to extract the price if you are fairly sure of the format.
The regex, below accounts for common European and USA formats, but assumes two digits to the right of the decimal point.

[**See the code in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3PEjs/)

```
var priceDivs   = document.querySelectorAll ("div.detailPrice");
for (var J = priceDivs.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var oldPriceParts   = priceDivs[J].textContent.match (/^(?:\s|\D)*([0-9\.,]*)(\d{2})\D*$/);
    if (oldPriceParts.length === 3) {
        var newPrice    = parseInt ('0' + oldPriceParts[1].replace (/[\.,]/g, ""), 10)
                        + parseInt (oldPriceParts[2], 10) / 100
                        ;
        // DO WHATEVER MANIP YOU WANT HERE.
        newPrice        = newPrice * 1.3;

        priceDivs[J].textContent = '€ ' + newPrice.toFixed (2).toLocaleString ();
    }
    else {
        console.log ("**Unexpected price format!** ", priceDivs[J]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)
It doesn't always have two digits after the comma but I guess I can account for that.
The "how do I get this damn value" was the confusing part for me.

Comment: You're welcome.  Beware that extracting free-form prices from text can get rather complicated -- especially if currency/locale is variable, There should be plenty of other Q's that discuss that, though.  It's a shame about the decimal digits, because that would greatly simplify things.

Comment: Indeed. Luckily in this case its € only. I will only have to account for the case where its just an integer but thats atleast something I can do with my existing JavaScript knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

So I wrote this little function in javascript that does that for you. Here's the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iyeluz/2/edit) for it.

```
function test(d){
    price=d.innerHTML;        //grabs the text that's inside your div
    price = parseInt(price.substring(2));    //skips the euro sign and converts to int
    newPrice=price+5;      // does some math with the price
    d.innerHTML='€ ' + newPrice;    // replaces the text within that div
}
```

I made it such that when you click on the price, this function gets called. If you look at the JSBin, it will make a lot more sense.

This is one of the many ways you can do this. Another way is using a javascript framework called [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/). That framework has a function called [update](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/update) that works as follows:

```
<div id="fruits">carrot, eggplant and cucumber</div>
Passing a regular string:


$('fruits').update('kiwi, banana and apple');
// -> HTMLElement
$('fruits').innerHTML
// -> 'kiwi, banana and apple'
```

Again. There are other methods of doing this as well. You just have to look for them. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't thought it would be that easy.
It ignores the value after the decimal comma though. But thats fine, I think I can figure the rest out myself from here on.

Comment: @Ignoring that is part of the function parseInt. It stops as soon as it finds a non-numeric character. As long as you find another way to parse your number out that string, you should be golden.

Comment: Ok one more thing. How do I use this now, because I still don't get the value I want if I dont replace the div class with the one you used.
I tried:
`function test(d){
        price=d.innerHTML;
        price = parseFloat(price.substring(2));
        newPrice=price+3;
        d.innerHTML='€ ' + newPrice;
    }
    
    document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(<div class="detailPrice" style="float:left;width:180px">,<div class="detailPrice" style="float:left;width:180px" onClick="test(this)">);`

but that didn't work

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need to replace the whole div or just the text within it?

Comment: Well no just the text within but I would need to add the `onClick="test(this)"` in order to make this work as far as I can see?
I can't see how the function itself would get the correct tag.

Comment: Well how? That is my whole question :D
I'm using Greasemonkey, like said in the question. I don't have access to the site at all. I need to inject the value with Greasemonkey.

Comment: E: Sorry, I accepted the answer from @Brock Adams now as it fits a little better to my question :)
But still thanks a lot for you answer.